# How can I filter search results by category in ExpressionEngine 1.6.8

Tags: expressionengine

I have inherited search results template in an EE 1.6.8 install and would like to filter the results by category. This is possible to a point but the paged results are incomplete i.e display an inconsistent no. of results. I believe this is because the template is doing n+1 queries (bad enough in the first place) in a nested query via a custom localisation module (However, if I remove that then my content is not localised)

```
{exp:search:search_results disable="member_data|trackbacks" orderby"date" paginate="bottom" limit="10" show_expired="no" show_future_entries="no" }
{count}
                        {exp:localisation:local_query  local_sql_url_title="content-from-url-title" page_url_title="{url_title}" } 

{categories}
{if category_group ==1}
                 {if category_name == "Videos"} 
<p>              
...
                        </p>
                {if:elseif category_name == "audio"}
                    <p>
...
                {if:elseif category_name == "Images"} 
...
                    {if:elseif weblog_short_name == "gpress-releases"  } 
...


                    {if:elseif weblog_short_name == "articles" } 
...


                    {if:elseif weblog_short_name == "press-kits"  }
...
{/if}
                {/if}

            {/categories}               

                        {/exp:localisation:local_query }    
                {/exp:search:search_results}
```

Does anyone know how I can filter search results by category when an article might be assigned to more than one category (in another group)? I need to display slightly different content e.g. a different icon based on the category name.

Upgrading to EE 2.x is not an option at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just upload your category icon as the category image for each category? Your template will be much cleaner and simpler:

```
{exp:search:search_results disable="member_data|trackbacks" orderby"date" paginate="bottom" limit="10" show_expired="no" show_future_entries="no"}
    {count}
    {exp:localisation:local_query local_sql_url_title="content-from-url-title" page_url_title="{url_title}" } 
        {categories}<img src="{category_image}" alt="{category_name}" class="category-icon" />{/categories}               
    {/exp:localisation:local_query }    
{/exp:search:search_results}`
```